# Compile Tensorflow programs with custom compiler

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to compile a very simple Tensorflow program (which only prints the Tensorflow version) with my company's c compiler but the libtensorflow.so I downloaded from Tensorflow's offical website is incompatible with our c compiler.

My company's c compiler is pretty much just a standard gcc but gcc can compile the program and our custom compiler cannot.

My colleague told me I have two options: (1) replace Bazel's compiler with our compiler and use Bazel to compile the program or (2) Compile the program with Bazel first then compile the program using our compiler and include the pb.h files generated by Bazel (because those bazel files can only be generated by Bazel).

I'm not sure how to do (!) but I tried (2). The problem with (2) is I got erros saying the protoc was generated by an older version and I'm not sure how to change to the right version.

Some additional information: (1) The OS is Linux, (2) I do not have the privilege to use sudo commands, (3) I cannot access system directories (e.g. /usr/local)

Is there any hope I can make this work? You may ask why not just build the program with Bazel. It's because our company's program needs to be run by our company's simulator and the simulator only accepts program generated by our company's compiler.

Comment: Have you tried compiling Bazel from source? https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/install-compile-source.html

Comment: I used the binary installer (.sh) to install Bazel. Would compiling Bazel from source make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to build tensorflow with Bazel, and tell Bazel to use your C/C++ compiler. The easiest way is to set the CC and CXX environment variables to point to your compiler's executable. If it is really a drop-in replacement of GCC, then it should work and after building you should get a tensorflow binary compiled with your custom compiler.

If special flags are needed then you should make a custom toolchain in Bazel to tell it how to use your compiler, it is a bit complex but not much. Instructions for that are at https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain

Comment: Other sources say I can only edit tools/cpp/CROSSTOOL and not need to do the whole thing as stated in the tutorial. There is CROSSTOOL and CROSSTOOL.tpl. Which one should I modify? Also, what do I need to do to tell Bazel to use the CROSSTOOL I have modified? I tried to compile Bazel with compile.sh but Bazel disregards everything I have changed in CROSSTOOL.